# subprocess.Popen and ipython

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.4

(Working with python3.4 on a Ubuntu 16.04)

I'm trying to understand if the behavior I have is a feature or something else.

I'm starting an ipython shell, and starting a process-

```
subprocess.Popen("MyProcess")
```

After that, I tail a file-

```
! tail -f a_log
```

Then, I press control+c in order to exit the tail.

The result is that MyProcess is also stoped.

I see this when there are several process running = they are all killed.

Also tried to redirect stdout and stderr to subprocess.DEVNULL, but this did not help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with iPython. If you wrote a script that did the same thing, and then used `Popen("tail"...).wait()`, you'd get the same result. If you write a C program that opened two pipes, and you hit ctrl+c, both pipes would be closed. That's just how Unix works.

Comment: As stated, this is expected behavior. You can, however, install a signal handler, to catch the signal generated by ctrl+c (SIGINT) in your Python code, and then do something else than exiting. I doubt you want to do that, though.

Comment: Thank you @KenKinder for the explanation. Can you write this comment as and answer? I would like to approve it...

Comment: Sure. I'll add a little more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that ctrl+c causes a [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) to be sent to the *process group* of the foregrand task. The second thing you need to know is that the process group includes your Python process and its open subprocesses.

For example, I'll recreate your experiment without iPython, using a 4-line script:

```
import subprocess, os

pipe1 = subprocess.Popen('sleep 500', shell=True)
pipe2 = subprocess.Popen('sleep 500', shell=True)
pipe3 = subprocess.Popen('tail -f /var/log/syslog', shell=True).wait()
```

As you can see, this opens two pipes to `sleep` (which do nothing for 500 seconds) and one pipe to `tail` and follow `/var/log/syslog`.

Now, with that running, I'm going to type `ps ax -O tpgid` into another terminal and see my running processes *including their group id*:

```
24083 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 python3 foo.py
24084 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 500
24085 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 sleep 500
24086 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c sleep 500
24087 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 sleep 500
24088 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c tail -f /var/log/syslog
24089 24083 S pts/9    00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

The first column is the process ID, the second column is the group ID, which is important.

If I run `kill -INT 24083`, which sends the `INT` (interrupt) signal to the 24083 *process group*, all processes in that group receive the signal and exit accordingly.

That's what's happening for you when you hit ctrl+c. The process group receives the signal, and each process is expected to exit per the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is what CTRL C does

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:

```
import os
def myspawn():
    os.setsid()
    path = os.environ["PATH"] + ":/home/another/path"
    env = {"PATH": path}
    os.execlpe("program.sh", env)

def myFunc():
    pid = os.fork()
    if (pid == 0):
        print("In child")
        myspawn()
    else:
        print("in father")
        return

myFunc()
```